# Is there a way to use pandas in django without using models or db

Tags: python, django, pandas, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

This may be a stupid question but I need help with a project I'm working on (also english isnt my first language so bear with me...). I'm developing a web app with Django to perform sentiment analysis of live tweets (using tweepy) and I am using a form to get from user input the keyword to search

```
from django import forms

class TwitterForm(forms.Form):
    keyword = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And now I have to fetch tweets using this function here

```
def get_tweets(self, query, count=100):
    tweets = tweepy.Cursor(self.api.search, q=query, lang="en", since='2021-01-01').items(count)
    cleaned_tweets = [self.clean_tweet(tweet.text) for tweet in tweets]
    sentiment_object = [TextBlob(tweet) for tweet in cleaned_tweets]
    #sentiment_object[0].polarity, sentiment_object[0]
    sentiment_values = [[tweet.sentiment.polarity, str(tweet)] for tweet in sentiment_object]
    #sentiment_values[0]
```

Now, I run this code on Colab and everything worked, I printed the fecthed tweets with pandas. But how does it work on Django? I wrote down this code in views.py but I've literally no clue...

```
def prediction(self, request):
sentiment_df = pd.DataFrame(self.sentiment_values, columns=["polarity", "tweet"])
sentiment_df["analysis"] = sentiment_df["polarity"].apply(self.getAnalysis)
#sentiment_df.head()

if request.method=='POST':
   self.api = TwitterSentClass()
   t=request.POST['keyword']
   result = self.api.get_tweets(query=t, count=100)
   


return render(request,'myapp/prediction.html',{})
```

I searched everywhere on internet and google and Pandas is always used for Django models or queries...How do I use pandas to just print fetched live tweets?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you're doing just fine. You don't have to have models, you can handle the request just as you're doing now. Django tells you _should_ use models when interacting with a relational db, but if you're not, you can use whatever you want. I would add a cautionary warning, if your request takes longer than 500ms you _may_ want to NOT do it in the same request and off load it, BUT that will complicate the code quite a lot. For a simple POC this is just fine.

Comment: You have tweets in `result` which can be passed to template and in template you can iterate over it to print on screen. It's just overview.